# AWS Quicksight to display latest record value

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am creating a dashboard in AWS Quicksight. I have imported a dataset from AWS S3 CSV file.

The csv file structure looks like this:

```
Date,Value1,Value2,Value3
...
2021-07-31,8,7,6
2021-08-31,10,20,30
2021-09-30,18,22,33
```

I would like to display the latest value of "Value1" column (i.e. the 18) and also the percentage change against the last value (i.e. 8/10 = 80%). Can I use Quicksight to do so? Thanks!